# Date time setting raspberry pi4b

Tags: boot

I am brand new to this, I have bought a pi4b starter kit, made all the connections as per the step by step instructions in the supplied booklet, connected to a monitor, and connected to my wireless net, Gigaclear, but that’s it I can go no further than the installed page as the system is telling me it cannot update the date / time, I have tried running the script sudo raspi- config several times , but it just keeps telling me that what I am seeing is correct, help please , but make it in easily understood language, I’m not that computer savvy

Comment: You say it is  "telling you" it cannot update the date and time. How is it telling you? By an error message? What is the message exactly?

Comment: Hi Alan, welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) You know that Unix/LInux is mainly using the command line? So lets start with it step by step. I assume that your internet connection does not work so that the time cannot be synchronized with a time server on the internet.  How are you connected to the internet? Is there an internet router? To get more details about this please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/112180/edit) your question and copy/paste the output of these commands to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but it is cured. It would appear that i had some sort of connectivity problem with my internet provider ?? Fortunately I have a mobile internet as well ( for our holiday stays), and it connected and updated straight away on that, and now is working fine on my household connection,, ( I was being told I didn’t have a secure connection ) , anyway , I’m up and running and am halfway through the section on scratch 3; enjoying

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.